# pip install doesn't find my highest installed version of python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My problem is that when I try to install a product that requires python >= 3.7, the installer fails, saying that it could not find the required python version, even though I do have python 3.8 installed.

I'm running Ubuntu for Windows 10 (the MS-store product.)

It comes with python 3.6 installed.

From a clean ubuntu install, I

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.8
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

At this point the command "python" is not mapped (not available), but I can run "python3" to get python3.6 or "python3.8" to get that version.
pip3 reports that it is using python 3.6.

```
pip3 --version 
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

So it appears that pip is not recognizing the python 3.8 that I have.

When I attempt my product install, it fails, indicating that

```
sudo pip3 install --verbose (mypackage name)
(... various messages...)
(requires-python:>=3.7) is incompatible with the pythonversion in use. Acceptable python versions are:>=3.7
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cbordplatform (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for (my package name)
```

How can I get pip3 to recognize my python3.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make *sure* that pip is using the correct version of Python, call it with the specific Python like this:

```
python3.8 -m pip ...
```